# How to divide a line into multiple line segments?

Tags: java, geometry, processing

I'm trying to divide a line into multiple segments. Because of that i've created a function below to try get sub points between two points. It's not quite working, but almost there. Ideally, i'd like to use it something like this:

```
subPoint(point1, point2, 5, 10);  // this would return the half way point
subPoint(point1, point2, 1, 10);  // this would return a point 1 tenth towrds point2
```

Here's the rough code below - any tips or pointers very welcome.

```
Vector subPoint(Vector startPoint, Vector endPoint, int segment, int totalSegments) {

  int division = (int)(totalSegments / segment);

  PVector divPoint = new PVector();

  int midX=(int)(startPoint.x+((endPoint.x-startPoint.x)/division));
  int midY=(int)(startPoint.y+((endPoint.y-startPoint.y)/division));

  divPoint.set(midX, midY, 0);

  return(divPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing your calculations with the following:

```
int midX = (startPoint.x + (int) ((double) (endPoint.x - startPoint.x) / (double) totalSegments) * segment);
int midY = (startPoint.y + (int) ((double) (endPoint.y - startPoint.y) / (double) totalSegments) * segment);
```

I transformed the values to doubles in order to make the calculations a little more accurate.  You may want to consider keeping the values as doubles as that will give you better accuracy on line segments.

Answer (score 2):

You're using integer math. Perhaps your Vector should be using floats or doubles instead?

Comment: The problem is the dividing by division which is an int but should be a float, also midX/Y should be floats.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Kris for the help. Here's the complete subPoint function Processing/Java code now working for anyone else who might need it.

```
PVector subPoint(PVector startPoint, PVector endPoint, int segment, int totalSegments) {

  PVector p1 = new PVector();

  float midX = (startPoint.x + (int) ((double) (endPoint.x - startPoint.x) / (double) totalSegments) * segment);
  float midY = (startPoint.y + (int) ((double) (endPoint.y - startPoint.y) / (double) totalSegments) * segment);

  p1.set(midX, midY, 0);   

  return(p1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this line

> int division = totalSegments = segment;

But I doubt you want to keep it :-) (do not know if there are more errors).